# REGEX: Allow only UPPERCASE and some special caracters and exclude all lowercaracters accents

Tags: regex, uppercase

i've a problem with my regex
here my rules :

- authorize UPPERCASE
- Exclude lowercase and accent
- <strike>authorize</strike>*(edited)* **Exclude** only thoses special caracters **& ' ( ) . _**

my regex is actually :

```
/^[A-Z][A-Z\s]*[^&'()._]$/i
```

that's almost all I need, but it accept for exemple

POTATOé

when it shouldn't

and it doesn't accept POTATOéé which is normal

if anyone has the solution it would be very helpful

Comment: It is useful to mention the programming language for Regexp questions.Modern Regexp implementations support Unicode properties such as `\p{Upper}`, which would match ANY uppercase letter, including e.g. É, if so desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly find the solution

```
^[A-Z\u0500-\uFFE5А-я\s^&'()._]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems with your Regex:

1. The character `^` inverts the selection of characters. You allow any character that does not match your allowed special characters
2. Currently, only one single special character at the end of the string is allowed.
3. You are using the modifier `i` which stands for case insensitive. Therefore lowercase letters are also matched.

Assuming the string has to start with an uppercase letter, and can contain uppercase letters, spaces and the specified special characters, your resulting regex could look something like this:

```
/^[A-Z][A-Z\s&'()._]*$/
```

Comment: The `.` inside `[]` is evaluated as a `.` and not as *any character*. Outside `[]`, it does mean what you have said.